# Using regex, with reserved characters in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am using the following regex syntax to match the 1st result in text with the following expression `(\plan)+(\d{5}))`.

The issues appear when I want to use this expression in Java, because the editor converts it to `((\\plan)+(\\d{5}))` (with 4 backslashes). Therefore I get the message from Intellj that I have an "Illegal category shorthand" at position `\\p`.

**Used code**

```
if(argIds.matches("((\\plan)+(\\d{5}))")){}
```

Comment: Why did you escape `p`? What do you mean? Do you want to match a backslash and then `plan` word?

Comment: I think you want to match a backslash as the first char. So, use ``"\\\\plan(\\d{5})"``

Comment: One issue is that you have too many closing parentheses: It should be `(\plan)+(\d{5})`. The second issue is exactly what @WiktorStribiżew said.